# Qt paintevent() not triggered

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to redraw a widget whenever `repaint()` is called, but for some reason it does not trigger `paintevent()`. For example, when I do something like this:

```
mLCD = new LCDui();
mLCD->drawBlank();
```

The constructor works just fine for the LCDui class, and draws a black widget, but when the `drawBlank()` method is called, the widget does not repaint. What am I missing? Thanks for the help! Here is the LCDui class and implementation:

**EDIT**

I have narrowed it down to the fact that the widget itself is not updating. If I do mLCD->show(); A new window appears with the correct image, which I can then use normally. However, the widget I want updated is not updated. This widget was promoted to the LCDui class.

**END EDIT**

lcdui.cpp

```
#include "lcdui.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QRgb>

LCDui::LCDui(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    image = new QImage(320,240,QImage::Format_RGB32);
    image->fill(qRgb(0,0,0));
}

LCDui::~LCDui()
{
    delete image;
    image = NULL;
}

void LCDui::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*event*/)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(QPoint(0,0),*image);
}

void LCDui::drawBlank()
{
    image->fill(qRgb(255,255,255));
    this->repaint();
}
```

lcdui.h:

```
#ifndef LCDUI_H
#define LCDUI_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QImage>

class LCDui : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LCDui(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~LCDui();
    void drawBlank();

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /*event*/);

private:
    QImage *image;
};

#endif // LCDUI_H
```

Comment: Is your paintEvent override being called at all? (Use debugger or qDebug to check). Note you don't need to use QImage on the heap (local member variable will work), and for this example here one would normally just use the QPainter directly: painter.fillRect(Qt::black, rect()); should do it

Comment: Do you run event loop? `update` will add a paint event to an event queue, so your widget will be redrawn only after returning to an event loop. You may try to call `repaint` instead.

Comment: The paintEvent override is indeed called. Yep, for this instance the it would make sense to do a fillRect(), but I am planning to change the raw image data at some point, so the paintevent() just needs to redraw the image. I tried it with repaint(), and still no update on the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was making a really silly mistake. I forgot to place said functions after I setup the UI.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->LCD_widget->drawBlank();
```

Works a lot better. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I have met similar problem.

I added widget manually but the *paintEvent* method of the widget i added to layout is not called.
After i set minimum size to added widget, problem is solved.